# How to install the required version of packages (jekyll-plugins) in the bundle manager?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions, jekyll-theme

I do not write very well in English, but I hope you understand me.

I decided to install the theme in my project on jekyll. Moved to the project folder. I ran the boundle install command, but some packages (from gemfile) were not installed. For example nakogiri since in my system there was no libxml2-dev (like so) for unpacking gem and (or) working with it (I so understood it). After fixing this and installing nokogiri, I started the Jekyll server with the command: jekyll serve -w. The server did not start because there were no packages:

```
listen (~> 3.0)
rouge (<4,> = 1.7)
rb-fsevent (> = 0.9.4, ~> 0.9)
ffi (<2,> = 0.5.0)
```

I installed the packages manually, but the latest versions of the packages were installed (Maybe it was not entirely reasonable at that time). Now the server does not work, does not start, requiring exactly these package versions, but boundle unstall does not fix the package versions, but writes that everything is fine.

I decided to install the package from the console by hand:

```
sudo bundle install --gemfile = listen-3.1
Do not run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and install your bundle as root will break this application for
all non-root users on this machine.

[!] There was an error parsing `listen-3.1`: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/user01/jekyllsites/myblog01/listen-3.1. Bundler can not continue.
```

I did this not work.

Question: What command from the console to install exactly the right version of packages?

Thank you for watching.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that the command `bundle install` completes with no errors.

Once it says all the gems have been installed, start the server with `bundle exec jekyll serve -w` to ensure that the correct gem versions are used.

Have in mind that Jekyll will halt the execution if there are configuration errors or missing template/asset files that have been declared.

Comment: I gave up Jekyll. When installing any theme, Gem incompatibility occurs. Authors of repositories with plugins for jekyll do not support backwards compatibility, apparently, or can not do it because of new technologies. And in one good theme there are a lot of plugins. One plugin can depend on another. In addition, in one theme there are a lot of plugins that use different versions of the same one plugin.

Comment: I tried to install the theme http://idratherbewriting.com/documentation-theme-jekyll/ but faced many problems. I have already entered all the commands, bundle update ok, bundle install ok. But the commands: jekyll serve -w and bundle exec jekyll serve -w produce errors, after solving one of which another appears, it is almost eternally infinite. Maybe it should be in the generators of sites, but I decided to try something else and compare it.